# Java - Continuing if condition is met

Tags: java

Sorry if the code looks a bit messy from here. It's my first time posting, and wasn't sure how to format it for the site as I'm under a time constraint.

I'm in quite a bind here. I've been trying to figure this out for quite a number of hours now, but can't seem to get around to solve it. I'm new to Java, so don't mind the code if it's a bit out of order, messy, or if it's a bit too long for what it does. My problem lies in the first few lines, under:

"Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);"

I was able to get the if statements working properly under the condition a number above or below 0 / 99 was entered, but if a number in between those two are entered, nothing happens. I searched in my textbook (Intro to Java Programming Comprehensive 10th edition), and can't seem to pinpoint the issue. Is there a way to have the program continue past the "if" statements and onto the lines of code that involve "input2"?

Thanks in advance!

```
package lab03;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab03 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 0-99: ");
     int input1 = input.nextInt();

       if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) 
       System.out.println(" Outside range. Please enter an integer between  0-99: ");
       input1 = input.nextInt();
       if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
        System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
        System.exit(0);

       System.out.println("Next, please enter another integer between 0-99: "); 
       int input2 = input.nextInt();

       if (input2 < 0 || input2 > 99) 
       System.out.println(" Outside range. Please enter an integer between 0-99:         `enter code here`");
       input2 = input.nextInt();
       if (input2 < 0 || input2 > 99) {
        System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
        System.exit(0);
```

Comment: All of your if checks are for out of range. what are you doing when number is in range?

Comment: You've wrapped you "good" condition within your failed condition block

Answer (score 1):

I would put them in a `while(scanner.hasNextInt())` loop and then if the condition is met call `continue` and it will go back to the beginning of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that those statements aren't reachable because you call `System.exit()`. `if` statements execute the next line beneath them OR everything inside the braces. As you can see you have an open brace, but you don't actually post the code where the brace closes. That means that everything below the following line will execute, including `System.exit()`.

```
if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
```

Your current program can be simplified to

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 0-99: ");

    int input1 = input.nextInt();
    if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
        System.out.println(" Outside range. Please enter an integer between  0-99: ");
    }

    input1 = input.nextInt();
    if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
        System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
        System.exit(0);

        // everything below this will never execute
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing curly braces that define the scope of what happens as a result of your first if statement.  You probably mean something like this

```
   if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
       System.out.println(" Outside range. Please enter an integer between  0-99: ");
       input1 = input.nextInt();
       if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
           System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
           System.exit(0);
       }
   }
```

but what is actually happening is that the program is waiting for a second try to input `input1`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you've wrapped your "continued" condition within your "failed" condition `if` block...

```
if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
    System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
    System.exit(0);

    // This is included within the failed block
    // but will never execute because of the previous statement
    System.out.println("Next, please enter another integer between 0-99: ");
    int input2 = input.nextInt();

    if (input2 < 0 || input2 > 99) {
        System.out.println(" Outside range. Please enter an integer between 0-99:         `enter code here`");
    }
    input2 = input.nextInt();
    if (input2 < 0 || input2 > 99) {
        System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

You should have a `else` condition which you want to execute when the `if` condition "fails" to be meet

```
if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
    System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
    System.exit(0);
} else {
    // This is included within the failed block
    // but will never execute because of the previous statement
    System.out.println("Next, please enter another integer between 0-99: ");
    int input2 = input.nextInt();

    if (input2 < 0 || input2 > 99) {
        System.out.println(" Outside range. Please enter an integer between 0-99:         `enter code here`");
    }
    input2 = input.nextInt();
    if (input2 < 0 || input2 > 99) {
        System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Remember `{...}` adds context to the code which it surrounds

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can also use a `do-while` loop to "trap" the user in a input loop, until they enter the correct value...

```
int input1 = -1;
do {

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 0-99: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();
    try {
        input1 = Integer.parseInt(text);
        if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
            System.out.print("Outside range. ");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        System.out.println(text + " is not a valid numerical value");
    }

} while (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99);
```

Now, remember, this will trap them until they enter a value between 0 and 99 inclusively, so you might want to consider adding a "escape" condition (ie "(type 'e' to exit) and then either break out of the loop or exit the program ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code only works for numbers that are greater than 99 and less than 0. You need an else statement for numbers that are between 0 and 99 for the program to continue.

```
    if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
   System.out.println(" Outside range. Please enter an integer between 0-99: ");
   input1 = input.nextInt();
   }else{
      //Continue on with program
   }
   if (input1 < 0 || input1 > 99) {
    System.out.println("Outside range. Program ending.");
    System.exit(0);
```